How to do representative validation dataset for LSTM
I am creating an LSTM model for predicting air pollution using weather parameters. My dataset is a combination of 4 years of measurements of air pollution and weather parameters merged together. My question is: how can I obtain a representative VALIDATION dataset for such a case for an LSTM model? For example, if I only take the last 10% of the dataset, my validation dataset will consist only measurements from the winter time, which is not representative. Do you know of a better way to approach this problem?
I actually tried using both the last 15% and 10%. The image below illustrates the two approaches. In one case (where the validation loss looks more "healthy"), I sliced the last 10% of the dataset. In the second attempt, I used 15%. I initially thought that using a larger portion would result in a more representative validation set (https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/), but it seems that's not the case, and I'm not sure why.
enter image description here
